# Printing.layoutPdf not working on some devices

Tags: ios, flutter, printing

i added this package to my code to print pdfs from a pdf link [Printing Package](https://pub.dev/packages/printing),

all tested well on my android phones, but some of the IOS such as IOS 11, didn't work on and keep loading and we keep waiting, and sometimes it crash and kick me of the app

here is my code:

```
if (!isLoading) {
                  setState(() {
                    isLoading = true;
                  });
                  try {
                    await http.get(Uri.parse(widget.link!)).then((value) async {
                      setState(() {
                        isLoading = false;
                      });

                      await Printing.layoutPdf(
                        onLayout: (_) => value.bodyBytes,
                        name: widget.title,
                        dynamicLayout: true,
                      );
                    });
                  } catch (e, trace) {
                    CustomDialogs().errorDialog(message: e as String? ?? 'Error Happend');
                    await Sentry.captureException(
                      e,
                      stackTrace: trace,
                    );
                  }
                }
```

thats the onPressed function, i just laod the url with http.get then insert the bodyBytes to the layout of Printing function